# java.lang.NullPointerException in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-xml, android-custom-view

I want to create scalebitmap in a custom view and when I want to add in a xml layout,xml gives an error `java.lang.NullPointerException` and ıt want to change some lines including my scalebitmap in my init() inside the onSizeChangedFunction().My code is below;

```
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    parentWidth=w;
    parentHeight=h;
    init();         // <--- This

    mBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}
```

and my init() function:

```
private void init()
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<2; i++)
    {   
        int imageResources;
        imageResources=getResources().getIdentifier("rakam"+i, "drawable", myContext.getPackageName());
        Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), imageResources);
        --> Bitmap scaledBitmap= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, parentWidth, parentHeight, false);
        rakamlar.add(scaledBitmap);

    }
}
```

The error not in the Logcat,it is in the eclipse's xml editör.
How can ı fix this?

Comment: are rakam0 and rakam1 both drawables ?

Comment: Nullpointers are easy to hunt down. Use debug to see what is actually null, and fix it from there. If some method returns null and you can not figure out why, come back with a more detailed question.

Comment: Posting your logcat output might make this question clearer.

Comment: the error is not in logCat it is in the eclipce's xml editör.

Answer (score 0):

Only a guess, but I think you might have some resources that cant be resolved while in "edit" mode under eclipse. To get you past the immediate error try:

```
private void init()
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<2; i++)
    {   
        int imageResources;
        // I suspect imageResources will be 0 while in edit mode..
        imageResources=getResources().getIdentifier("rakam"+i, "drawable", myContext.getPackageName());

        if(!isEditMode()) {
            // Don't access the unavailable resources..
            Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), imageResources);
            Bitmap scaledBitmap= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, parentWidth, parentHeight, false);
            rakamlar.add(scaledBitmap);
        }

    }
}
```